# Vagrant not showing proper error message

Tags: vagrant

After running below commands getting a failure without proper error message:

```
$ vagrant init hashicorp/precise32
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
default: Box Provider: virtualbox
default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'hashicorp/precise32'
default: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/precise32
==> default: Adding box 'hashicorp/precise32' (v1.0.0) for provider: virtualbox
default: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise32/versions/1.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box
==> default: Box download is resuming from prior download progress
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Failed writing body (1576 != 7240)
```

Answer (score 6):

By default vagrant downloads boxes(images) in home directory (~/.vagrant.d). If home has no enough space to store downloaded content you get this error.

To fix: setup default home to a different file system which has enough space

```
export VAGRANT_HOME=/data/vagrant/
```

Comment: This has been my problem, since it always errors out at the same downloaded %.